# Establishing connection with SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

This is a very elementary I realize, I have recently started working with asp.net and establishing a connection with an Access database was simple enough...

```
string insertedBookTitle;
conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;
                             Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("App_Data\\BookRateInitial.mdb"));
conn.Open()
```

What is the code I use to connect to SQL Server 2008, with the same name (BookRateInitial)?

Kind regards

Comment: This is a good link related to your question http://connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample connection string for standard security (username and pwd):

> ```
> Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
> ```

You need to do a:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
{
    conn.Open();
    //Use connection here
    using(SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that this sample code does not include exception handling (e.g. for conn.Open()). It's just to give you a hint. In a real situation you would have to add that support yourself.

Comment: Also note the `using` statements marceln has used, `using`'s are your friend Arianule!